# mysql return the total of rows for each user_id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM books LEFT JOIN users
           ON books.readby=users.user_id WHERE users.email IS NOT NULL";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
echo $row['readby']. " - read 10 books";
 } //while ends
```

this is the code I have so far. I am trying to retrieve the number of books read by each user
and echo the results. echo the user_id and number of books he/she read
books table is like this : id - name - pages - readby
the row readby contains the user id.any ideas/suggestions? I was thinking about using count() but Im not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: Can you update your answer with the dump of `DESC users`?

Comment: what do you mean ?  $count = $count[0]; what is this for? you position the variable count on the first item of the array? why

Comment: @fogsy I'll answer since this comment isn't directly under the related answer...  `mysql_fetch_array()` returns both numeric and associative keys.  `$row[0]` in that context would return the first column, which would be `COUNT(user_id)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subquery can return the count of books read per user. That is left-joined back against the main table to retrieve the other columns about each user.

**Edit** The `GROUP BY` had been omitted...

```
SELECT 
  users.*,
  usersread.numread
FROM 
  users
  /* join all user details against count of books read */
  LEFT JOIN  (
    /* Retrieve user_id (via readby) and count from the books table */
    SELECT 
      readby,
      COUNT(*) AS numread
    FROM  books
    GROUP BY readby
  ) usersread ON users.user_id = usersread.readby
```

In your PHP then, you can retrieve `$row['numread']` after fetching the result.

```
// Assuming you already executed the query above and checked errors...
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  // don't know the contents of your users table, but assuming there's a 
  // users.name column I used 'name' here...
  echo "{$row['name']} read {$row['numread']} books.";
}
```

Comment: @JaredFarrish MySQL is super-forgiving about the contents of the `GROUP BY` so in this case the subquery join is probably not even necessary.

Comment: Do you mean if you ran the subquery in the field list, it would still work?

Comment: great Michael, I am testing. Thank you

Comment: @JaredFarrish No I mean if users left-joined books directly and included `COUNT(readby)` in the field list without having to `GROUP BY` all other columns in the field list, just `GROUP BY user_id`

Comment: Oh right, ok. I'd think so too. Have you seen http://sqlfiddle.com? Too bad it can be time consuming to build a model for a question on this site ad hoc for it to be too useful, but interesting nonetheless.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I've used it a couple of times, mostly to correct things for users who've already prepared models for their questions. I've never taken the time to build one. It is really neat though.

Comment: @Michael usersread.numread there is no table usersread. the table books logs who read what and when. sorry for the confusion. anyway you can update the code ? books.readby column stores the ids. books.name are the names

Comment: @fogsy `usersread` is a table alias for the subquery, I know there's no real table of that name.  The way I have done this is to pull all user details along with the count of books read.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `count()` this way:

```
<?php
    $count = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM books LEFT JOIN users ON books.readby=users.user_id WHERE users.email IS NOT NULL GROUP BY `user_id`"));
    $count = $count[0];
?>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I think the OP wants to find how many books each user has read. This just more or less says "how many books are there read by users".

Comment: How can this have 4 upvotes? It does not do anything like what the OP is asking. This query returns _one row_, which contains the total number of books read by all users - i.e. the total number of rows in `books`.  On top of that, the PHP code performs no error checking on the query.